# Android stopwatch-like code falls out of sync, uses Date().getTime()

Tags: java, android, time

I've written an Activity that includes some stopwatch-like code. It really needs to be accurate, the problem is it gradually falls behind real time. Here's a smaller example of the problem code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int TIME_STEP = 500;    // milliseconds between updates
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private long mTimeElapsed = 0;

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable()
{
    private long mOldTime = 0;      // previous real time (ms) that run() was called

    public void run()
    {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, TIME_STEP);

        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        long realDelay = currentTime - mOldTime;    // the actual delay between successive calls to run()
        if (mOldTime != 0)
            mTimeElapsed += realDelay;
        Log.d(this.toString(), "time elapsed = " + mTimeElapsed/1000);

        // some slow operations here...

        mOldTime = currentTime;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTimeElapsed = 0;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

To illustrate the problem: after running the app for 8:23 (according to logcat timestamps) mTimeElapsed will be 456 seconds, or 7:36.

Since the delay between successive calls to run() is calculated using getTime() (i.e. it does not assume the real delay will be TIME_STEP), I can't understand why this falls out of sync?

I've tested this on an emulator and an actual device with the same results.

EDIT: the time results are for the posted code I.e. even with no "slow operations", though having work done here does seem to exacerbate the delay

Please don't just supply some alternative method of achieving the same thing. I'm not opposed to alternatives per se, I would just really like to know why this code doesn't work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that "some slow operations" take longer than 500ms and that your runnable is firing again, before the first instance is finished since you have postDelayed at the start, rather than at the end and your access to the time counters is not synchronised.

Comment: 2Simon: postDelayed() sends a message which is executed on the thread to which this handler is attached to. So, there should be no concurrent execution of multiple run() here.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear without more code exactly what is happening with your time calculations and the rest of the methods. However, what does seem clear is that your method does not seem to be measuring elapsed time correctly.

From what I can see, "elapsed time" is made up of the delay between run() calls. This is not going to be equal to elapsed time from the start of a program, since I assume plenty of small things happen between these points that would account for this accrual of lost time. Is there a reason you don't simply retrieve a start time and then just calculate the difference between the current time and start time?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the real app the stopwatch is started by a button, so I'm not so concerned about "elapsed time" not being quite from the program start. What concerns me is that the delay measured seems to be coming up a little short each time, and I can't see why! Yeah it did occur to me to just store a start time and always calculate elapsed time from that. That way it's a static reference point and should avoid errors accumulating. There are a couple of reasons I didn't go for that approach but maybe it's something to revisit. Even so, I'm still interested what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Several notes:

a) It's not clear what exactly are you trying to calculate in mTimeElapsed? Do you try to calculate overall time spend on activity? Do you try to calculate overall time spent in run() (approximately equal to time spend on "some slow operation")? Do you try to calculate overall time spent outside of run()?

b) Based on your code, what you do is you calculate time (approximately) which is spent BETWEEN exit from run() and next execution of run() (time spent oustide of run). Is this what you need?